# Visual Studio 2019 fails to add a new file to my project

Tags: c#, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I have a functions app project called Gorge.FunctionApp with the file path `D:\Kernelgen\Platform\Gorge\gorge-products-catalog\Gorge.FunctionApp`. However, when I try to add a new function, the dialog box just does not show up. When hit `Ctrl+Shift+A` to add a new file, I get the error as shown in the picture below.

[image: Error shows the file path is too long yet the folder path is less than 260 characters]

Below is the folder path which is less than 100 characters

[image]

I'd appreciate any kind of insight on this issue.

Comment: What happens if you use a name that does not exceed the given path length limit?

Comment: It still behaves the same. Even before as shown above, the path is not above the limit. To be precise, the path is 68 characters long. I would not expect such an error but it is happening

Comment: Have you tried to restart vs?

Comment: I think you better log a bug report at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html and explain every step you've taken to get to this error.

Comment: I restarted Visual Studio and still the same. I will log the issue as thomasvdb has suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some installation issue to me as i tried in Visual studio 2019 Preview edition and it worked for me.

I would suggest you to repair your VS 2019 and try it again.

Also if you still see this an issue , feel free to report it to VS team by clicking on following link in visual studio.

[image]

Hope it helps.